# Two active transformations cannot flow into a passive transformation in Informatica Cloud

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I am facing an issue with Informatica Cloud. I am very new to the system. I need to parse a XML which has various nodes in it. For this I have used a `Hierarchy Parser` and from that to a `Sorted output` and used `Joiner` to join different nodes in the XML. Since there were different Joiners, I have clubbed them into a singe `Joiner` and send the output to the Target. But I am getting an error `Two active transformations cannot flow into a passive transformation.`. Informatica cloud help provided me the below link [ERROR: "Two Active transformations cannot flow into a passive transformation" while validating a mapping in IICS][1]

[1]: https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/pages/59/501727.aspx, but I am not sure which is the Passive Transformation here. I am using only `Source, Hierarchy Parser, Sorted Output, Joiners and Target`. I am in a critical situation. So any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not very clear on multiple joiner etc.  canyou pls add a picture. So, here are some basics - i. if you want to 2 source, you need 1 joiner, if you want to join 3 source, you need to use 2 joiners and so on. ii. sometime you need to do self join, you need to sort the data before joining.  iii. you can join or union two active transformations iv. active transformation is something that can change number of rows,

Comment: @KoushikRoy That is really helpful. I was using one joiner for multiple Sorters. That was the issue. As you said, I have changed to two joiners for 3 Sorters. It worked well. But I am facing some issues on cache now. However thank you very much.

Comment: used this as answer. let me know if ou need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls follow some basics while working with joiner/multiple sources -
i. use n-1 joiners for n sources/pipelines. So, if you want to join 2 source, you need 1 joiner, if you want to join 3 sources, you need to use 2 joiners and so on.
ii. sometime you need to do self join, you need to sort the data before joining.
iii. you can join or union two active transformations
iv. active transformation is something that can change number of rows

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped

Comment: If they cant use multiple joins in informatica cloud, why did they give the option to us? I am also facing the issue. It is too wierd

Comment: Its not even in infa powercenter version.